# Admob Interstitial not covering the full space Swift

Tags: swift, admob, adsense

i am trying to implement admob Interstitial ads to my mobile game for the first time. i setup everything and it works. but for some reason the ads are not utilising the entire screen space.

It looks like this

[image]

**GameViewController**

```
 var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadInterstialAds()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationReceived2(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAds"), object: nil)

        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "background_Music", ofType: "wav")
        let audioNSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

        do { backendAudio = try  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioNSURL as URL)
        } catch { print("error background") }

        backendAudio.numberOfLoops = -1
        backendAudio.volume = 8
        backendAudio.play()


        let scene = MainMenuScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))

                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                // Present the scene
                if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                    view.presentScene(scene)

                    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                    view.showsFPS = false
                    view.showsNodeCount = false
                }
    }


    func loadInterstialAds(){
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-70675555555551199/5275555553")
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
    }
    func showInterstialAds() {
        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    }


    @objc func notificationReceived2(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        if let message = notification.userInfo?["message"] as? adTypes {
            if message == .interstitial {
                showInterstialAds();
            } else if message == .loadInterstitial {
                loadInterstialAds()
            }
        }
    }
```

and am sending a broadcast to show ads from my **GameOverScene: SKScene**

can someone help me to fix this tnx